Applying subdivision surface modifier failed

I have been using blender for about 15 years now and never had this problem.
I'm using blender 4.1.1, the latest blender version on steam.
I really just added a normal icosphere, added a subdivision surface modifier and don't see any visible changes when I change the values. When I want to apply it, I get the error message at the bottom that it failed.
Why is this happening? Does anyone please know a fix?

Hello, maybe there's a problem with an addon?

My 2 cents: I usually have such a display in the right hand side panel (red icon and no On Cage icon) when I miss click and drop the Levels Viewport to 0. Yours seem equal to 2 however...

I suspect you have simplify enabled, which is limiting the preview subdivision levels to 0.

@Nathan Deactivating simplify was the solution, thank you!

@Nathan: a stupid question... Where is this "simplify" thing ?

@StefLAncien properties/render/simplify

Max Subdivision under Render Properties was set to 0. Increasing this value or simply deactivating Simplify was the solution.

